# .NET 5.0 LGPL self-contained executable

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-5

.NET 5.0 builds self-contained executable which doesn't extract files to the disk.

It means that if you have a LGPL package, it will be linked into executable and it requires your application to be LGPL as well.

Is there any option to prevent linking LGPL dll into the self-contained executable ?

Thanks.

Comment: “it will be linked into executable and it requires your application to be LGPL as well.” — Source for that claim please? That isn’t at all obvious.

Comment: You can read about .NET 5.0 single file applications here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file  and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/ . 
.NET 5.0 single file application is not a self extracting zip as it was in the previous versions. It loads all file in memory. This means that LGPL package doesn't exist on the disk which means it is the same as it would be statically linked. Everything that is statically linked to LGPL must be licensed as LGPL too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use property IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract.
This restores file extraction behavior similar to way it works in .NET Core 3.1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#other-considerations

Comment: How is this related to LGPL? What makes you think that unzipping changes the LGPL requirements? You're still deploying and using the LGPL library directly, so the application still needs to be LGPL. If you want to use eg iTextSharp for commercial purposes, you need to pay or release your application as LGPL, self-contained or not.

Comment: Because the end user can change the library to anything he wants.

Comment: Not at all. Doing so would break the application and require recompilation. Not that it matters. You used the library in your application. You have to make it LGPL. If you're found out you'll get sued and have to pay damages to the library's ownerr

Comment: The only way you can bypass LGPL is if you *don't* distribute the application, eg if you provide it as a service running on your own servers. That's what cloud providers do with their own services - they use LGPL libraries but don't have to make their services LGPL as well, since they only allow customers to use them

Comment: It doesn’t require recompilation. You simply replace the library.